# How to copy content of one text file to another text file with only filename and its extension using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, text, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a text file which has list of files with their full path along with extensions, what i want is to copy this list of files to another text file only with their filename and extension and not the entire path.

For eg - Copying demo.txt content to test.txt

```
Demo.txt 

C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\ConfigurationUtility.BackUp.exe.config
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\ConfigurationUtility.exe.Config
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\ConfigurationUtility.WMIExtensions.XML
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\Microsoft.Administration.dll
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\ModelConfiguration.xml
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\Newtons.Json.dll
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\Data\Help\List User Guide.pdf
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\Data\Help\ListHelp.chm
C:\Demo\Excluded Files\AppData\List\Data\Help\intel Load Balancing.pdf


test.txt

ConfigurationUtility.BackUp.exe.config
ConfigurationUtility.exe.Config
ConfigurationUtility.WMIExtensions.XML
Microsoft.Administration.dll
ModelConfiguration.xml
Newtons.Json.dll
List User Guide.pdf
ListHelp.chm
intell Load Balancing.pdf
```

How can i do that using PowerShell?

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I know...I'm bad...

Comment: Imma call the karma police on you @EBGreen

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 There, I made it a community wiki so at least I won't get any rep from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Content demo.txt | %{Split-Path $_ -leaf} | Set-Content test.txt
```

To answer the other question that you didn't ask in the first place (since I am already in the doghouse for providing code to posters that don't try first):

```
Get-Content demo.txt | %{(Split-Path $_ -leaf).Split('.')[-1]} | Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @EBGreen, It works but want can i append to this code to copy only extensions and not the filename.

Comment: So you want to answer a question that is different from the one you asked?

Comment: I am not a PowerShell expert i am still in learning phase of it and i also tried a small code using get-content  but it was far away from what you wrote. So that's the reason i had to post the question to get the answer whether it is possible or not? But anyways Unlike others you were not mean, Thanks :-)

Comment: For future reference, a) Always ask the question that you actually want answered. b) even if you aren't coming close to finding the answer yourself at least post the things that you have tried. It tells us what level your knowledge is at and that you at least made an effort.